# WinDBG hits the breakpoint but doesn't step through (User-mode)

Tags: windows, windbg, usermode

The breakpoint at the start of the function is hit and I can see that but after that it doesn't step through the function rather it just jumps instead of stepping through so I can verify all the variables

Comment: Are you in source mode or in assembly mode? release or debug version of the binary?

Comment: Debug version and source mode

Comment: That's too little information, IMHO. Can you show commands, source, assembly, ...? What programming language? Does the compiler and/or linker produce good PDBs? Are the symbols correct?